# Suppose $A \cup B$ is measurable then prove the following property with respect to Outer and Inner measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that in general  $$\lambda^*(A)+\lambda^*(B)\geq\lambda^*(A\cup B)+\lambda^*(A\cap B)$$
and
$$\lambda_*(A)+\lambda_*(B)\leq\lambda_*(A\cup B)+\lambda_*(A\cap B)$$

$\lambda^*$ is the outer measure defined as $\inf\left\{\lambda(G)|A\subset G \;is\;Open\right\}$and $\lambda_*$ is the inner measure defined as $\sup\left\{\lambda(K)|K\subset A \;is\;Compact\right\}$

We, a priori, know the countable subadditivity property of both inner(With disjoint sets) and outer measure(In general).

I tried expressing $A\cup B$ as disjoint union of $A\backslash B$ and $B$ and use the existing countable subadditivity property. But I get stuck at a point where I have to combine the $\lambda^*(A\cap B)$ with $\lambda^*(A\backslash B)$ which doesn't work out well.

Another attempt I tried, in case of outer measure, is to set $G_A\supset A$ and $G_B\supset B$, We can then write. $$\lambda(G_A)+\lambda(G_B)=\lambda(G_A\cup G_B)+\lambda(G_A \cap G_B)$$
And try to take Infimum both side but I am not sure how can I use it.

P.S. :The measure of Open set is defined in terms of union non-overlapping special rectangle(parallel to coordinate axes and closed) and compact set as a limit of open sets.

Comment: Is the $\lambda_*$ also the outer measure?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention in the question. Let me fix.

Comment: You know that for open and closed sets, you get equality with the actual measure.  You can cover one side by $U, V$, and one side by $U \cup V$ and $U \cap V$.  Show using the actual measure that you get equality.  Now notice that you proved the first part, because then for every open cover of the lhs you get one of the same size on the rhs, so when you take liminf you get the inequality.  The other case is similar, but show compact implies measurable for a Borel measure by using the finite open cover property of compact sets first.